# Transforming CSV data with commas with XSLT

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I am working with CSV data that I need to transform into XML via XSLT.

**Example:**

**CSV**

```
Title,Artist
Empire Burlesque,Bob Dylan
Hide your heart,Bonnie Tyler
```

**XSL**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="input" select="unparsed-text('example.csv')" />

  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="rows" select="tokenize($input, '\r?\n')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="csvHeaders">
    <Heading>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($rows[1], ',')">
      <xsl:element name="header">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </Heading>
    </xsl:variable>
          
    <xsl:variable name="step1-xml">
      <xsl:for-each select="remove($rows, 1)">
        <data>
          <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ',')">
            <xsl:element name="elm{position()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </data>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

      
    <CSVData>  
    <xsl:copy-of select="$csvHeaders" />
    <Dataset>
             <xsl:for-each select="$step1-xml/data">
            <item>
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
                    <xsl:element name="{translate($csvHeaders/Heading/header[$i], ' :', '  __')}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Dataset> 
  </CSVData>

</xsl:template>
```

**Output**

```
<CSVData>
   <Heading>
      <header>Title</header>
      <header>Artist</header>
   </Heading>
   <Dataset>
      <item>
         <Title>Empire Burlesque</Title>
         <Artist>Bob Dylan</Artist>
      </item>
      <item>
         <Title>Hide your heart</Title>
         <Artist>Bonnie Tyler</Artist>
      </item>
   </Dataset>
</CSVData>
```

This output is correct/as intended. Where I'm running into issues if my CSV data contains commas within the values. For example, if the CSV was slightly altered to be:

**CSV**

```
Title,Artist
Empire Burlesque,Bob Dylan
"Hide,your,heart",Bonnie Tyler
```

This will throw an error (as the ordering will be off during the second/currently final stage of my transformation pipeline, where elements are given proper names). While I can get away with replacing the commas pre-xsl in some cases, this adds a step to my process and is not possible in some of my planned uses. Ideally, I would want the values with commas to output within a single element, as shown below.

**Ideal Output**

```
<CSVData>
   <Heading>
      <header>Title</header>
      <header>Artist</header>
   </Heading>
   <Dataset>
      <item>
         <Title>Empire Burlesque</Title>
         <Artist>Bob Dylan</Artist>
      </item>
      <item>
         <Title>Hide, your, heart</Title>
         <Artist>Bonnie Tyler</Artist>
      </item>
   </Dataset>
</CSVData>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Well, various people have done that before, see e.g. http://andrewjwelch.com/code/xslt/csv/csv-to-xml_v2.html

Comment: I don't think that works as expected. Note also that not only commas but also newlines and escaped quotes can appear within quotes in a CSV. This is all of course solvable, but perhaps it would be easier use a tool other than XSLT?

Comment: Nearly every modern programming language maintains libraries to read CSV and build XML.